# Dell PowerEdge R710 - how to assign IP address to 4 available NICs and iDRAC?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a DellPowerEdge R710 server, brand new, with no configuration. How can I assign the IP address to its 4 NICs and iDRAC? Thanks!

I would like to install ESXi 5.5 on that server and be able to manage it remotely.

Comment: Do you mean you just have one IP address?  What operating system is installed?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Please provide more details such as the OS you are going to install and what type of configuration you wish to achieve with the network interfaces.

Comment: Judging from this and your past questions here on ServerFault, you might consider taking a step back and realizing that you need to learn more about the equipment and software you are wanting to run direct from the OEMs or through formal training avenues.

Comment: You should stop wasting our time and go speak to your manager about getting some much needed education - you really need it. You might also find http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ an interesting if uncomfortable read.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the DRAC BIOS by using CTRL+E during POST, can set IP address in this BIOS for iDRAC interface.
For 4 ports on the integrated NIC you set IP address during OS installation or network interfaces configuration process.

Comment: Ok, I will do it for iDRAC with no problems now, thanks! ;) I would like to install on this server ESXi. How can I assign IP addresses for my 4 NICs with ESXi? And what do you mean by `network interfaces configuration process`? Can it be done in BIOS too? Or through iDRAC?

Comment: you can set ip addressing to your 4 ports through ESXi configuration setup menu, once you install OS, hence ESXi in your case.

Comment: Hmm, havent seen such option in ESXi before. Can it be done through iDRAC too? (Instead of ESXi way)? Will check it tomorrow

Comment: Heres what I meant: http://i59.tinypic.com/2441rbq.png I can only configure the management network with ESXi, what about other, 4 ports?

Comment: so once you configure your management network, you assign ips to other interfaces through ESXi shell cli or Vcenter vsphere client.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer covered the iDRAC part of the question this will cover the VMWare ESX part.  On the console of the host you can configure the management network for the host.  As your [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2441rbq&s=8#.UvpsbvldU74) indicates you can select which NICs to configure for management.  By selecting all of the NICs this will place them on the same virtual switch and into an active-standby team.  The host will be accessible from the IP you designate as the management IP in the console.

Using the VMWare vSphere Client you can configure multiple virtual switches with different subnets and even assign them directly to an individual NIC to segment traffic onto multiple networks.  Please reference the [VMWare Networking Documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-networking-guide.pdf) for more information.

It is also possible to configure the network interfaces via the [console or ssh session](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000258).

Please refer to VMWare documentation for best practices regarding networking with virtual hosts.